How to handle limits for marginal distributions when the domain is restricted?
I am working on finding marginal distributions using the following definition of marginal distribution function:
Definition:
Let $F(\mathbf{x})$ be the joint distribution function of $(X_1, X_2, \dots, X_m)$. For each $k$, $k = 1, 2, \dots, m$, we define the marginal distribution function of $X_k$ as:
$$
F_{X_k}(x_k) = \lim_{\substack{x_i \to \infty \\ \forall i \neq k}} F(\mathbf{x})
$$
where the limit is applied to all coordinates except for $x_k$.
My issue arises when the domain of the joint distribution is restricted. For example, consider the following joint distribution function:
$$
F(x, y) =
\begin{cases}
    0, & \text{if } x < 0 \text{ or } y < 0 \text{ or } x \geq y, \\
    \frac{2x^2y^2 - x^4}{16}, & \text{if } 0 \leq x < y, \, 0 \leq y < 2, \\
    \frac{8x^2 - x^4}{16}, & \text{if } 0 \leq x < 2, \, y \geq 2, \\
    1, & \text{if } x \geq 2, \, y \geq 2, \, x < y.
\end{cases}
$$
In this case, the joint CDF has different behaviors in different regions of the $(x, y)$ plane. How should I interpret the limit $x_i \to \infty$ when the joint CDF is restricted to a finite region? How can I proceed with finding the marginal distributions for $X$ and $Y$ in such cases?

While I'm sure you want a more "mathematical" answer, here (in my old age) is how I deal with that.  Using Mathematica:
(* Define joint cdf *)
F[x_, y_] := Piecewise[{
   {(2 x^2  y^2 - x^4)/16, 0 <= x < y && 0 <= y < 2},
   {(8 x^2 - x^4)/16, 0 <= x < 2 && y >= 2},
   {1, x >= 2 && y > 2 && x < y}}, 0]

(* Find the joint pdf *)
jointPDF = D[F[x, y], x, y]


(* Marginal pdf of Y *)
Integrate[jointPDF, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}] // Simplify


(* Marginal pdf of X *)
Integrate[jointPDF, {y, 0, \[Infinity]}] // Simplify


And this can be done in any other symbolic algebra system (Maple, MATLAB, etc.).
